# Comparar filas, eliminar repetidos y juntarlas en una sola despendiendo de condición

Tags: python, python-3.x, condiciones, txt

tengo el siguiente problema para PYTHON, yo tengo un archivo txt de esta manera:

txt:

```
'coordenada': [{'origen':'4235433', 'destino':'5544225'}], 'id': [{'nombre':'2345', 'nombre':'3432'}]    
'coordenada': [{'origen':'4235433', 'destino':'5544346'}], 'id': [{'nombre':'2345', 'nombre':'3432'}]    
'coordenada': [{'origen':'4235433', 'destino':'5544890'}], 'id': [{'nombre':'2345', 'nombre':'3432'}]    
...    
'coordenada': [{'origen':'7423333', 'destino':'5544225'}], 'id': [{'nombre':'9295', 'nombre':'4567'}]    
'coordenada': [{'origen':'7423333', 'destino':'5544346'}], 'id': [{'nombre':'9295', 'nombre':'4567'}]
...
```

Como se puede ver el 'id' no cambia solo la coordenada, me gustaría unir en una sola linea las coordenadas y un único 'id' de esta manera quedaría así:

```
'coordenada': [{'origen':'4235433', 'destino':'5544225'}],'coordenada': [{'origen':'4235433', 'destino':'5544346'}],'coordenada': [{'origen':'4235433', 'destino':'5544890'}],'id': [{'nombre':'2345', 'nombre':'3432'}]    
'coordenada': [{'origen':'7423333', 'destino':'5544225'}], 'coordenada': [{'origen':'7423333', 'destino':'5544346'}],'id': [{'nombre':'9295', 'nombre':'4567'}]
```

No se como sería una posible forma de hacer esto **sin manejarlo mediante pandas** ya que no es posible por el entorno.

Comment: Si publicas el código que has escrito hasta el momento, seguro que alguien te ayudara. Podrías empezar por leer el archivo de entrada ...

Comment: En tu ejemplo no son diccionarios válidos: "{'nombre':'2345', 'nombre':'3432'}" contiene llaves duplicadas. La salida que muestras tampoco son diccionarios válidos. ¿Es así o tengo un problema de interpretación?

Comment: Así es, no pretendo tener diccionarios ni que estos tengan sentido ya que quiero tratarlo como texto, respecto al código empleado hasta ahora a sido para eliminar espacios y separarlos en filas para reescribirlos en otro txt mediante las funciones replace y .write, lo que me gustaría saber es si hay alguna función que me permita cortar y pegar los datos como he mencionado, Gracias.

Comment: Si fueran diccionarios, sería elemental. Si no, se complica, porque hay que parsear a mano.

Answer (score 3):

Una solución sin pandas.

Primero construimos un generador que nos devuelve cada línea del archivo dividida en dos partes: coordenadas e id.

Para dividir cada línea simplemente buscamos el texto `'id'`, que no ocurre en ninguna otra parte de la línea.

```
def split_line(nombre_archivo):
    """
    Generador que devuelve una linea parseada en (coord, id)

    :param nombre_archivo: Nombre del archivo de datos
    :yield: (coord, id)
    """
    with open(nombre_archivo, "r") as datos:
        for linea in datos:
            index = linea.index("'id'")
            coord = linea[:index]
            id = linea[index:]
            yield coord, id
```

El `yield` funciona como `return`, sólo que la función no pierde su estado y continua iterando.

También definimos una función para imprimir cada tupla (coordenadas, id), donde `coordenadas` es la lista de coordenadas acumuladas por id.

```
def print_data(coordenadas, id):
    """
    Imprime la lista de coordenadas y su id.

    :param coordenadas:
    :param id:
    """
    for coord in coordenadas:
       print(coord, end="")
    print(id, end="")
```

Con eso se nos facilita el recorrer el archivo y acumular las coordenadas de un mismo id, que suponemos consecutivas:

```
out = []
id  = None
for coord, pos in split_line("test.txt"):
    if id is not None and id == pos:
        out.append(coord)
    else:
        if id is not None:
            print_data(out, id)
        id = pos
        out = [coord]
print_data(out, id)
```

produce:

```
'coordenada': [{'origen':'4235433', 'destino':'5544225'}], 'coordenada': [{'origen':'4235433', 'destino':'5544346'}], 'coordenada': [{'origen':'4235433', 'destino':'5544890'}], 'id': [{'nombre':'2345', 'nombre':'3432'}]
'coordenada': [{'origen':'7423333', 'destino':'5544225'}], 'coordenada': [{'origen':'7423333', 'destino':'5544346'}], 'id': [{'nombre':'9295', 'nombre':'4567'}]

resultado que podemos comparar con el pedido:

'coordenada': [{'origen':'4235433', 'destino':'5544225'}], 'coordenada': [{'origen':'4235433', 'destino':'5544346'}], 'coordenada': [{'origen':'4235433', 'destino':'5544890'}], 'id': [{'nombre':'2345', 'nombre':'3432'}]    
'coordenada': [{'origen':'7423333', 'destino':'5544225'}], 'coordenada': [{'origen':'7423333', 'destino':'5544346'}], 'id': [{'nombre':'9295', 'nombre':'4567'}]
```

Desde luego el código se puede adaptar para grabar un archivo de salida, sustituyendo los `print` por `write`.

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos por las respuestas !! Me han servido mucho de ayuda !

Answer (score 2):

Otra idea. Primero recorremos todo el archivo dividiendo cada línea por la cadena `", 'id':"`. En los dos trozos resultantes tendremos una coordenada y un id. Usamos un diccionario para ir guardando todas las coordenadas que aparezcan para un mismo id. De este modo no es necesario suponer que los id iguales ocurran en líneas consecutivas.

Usar un `defaultdict(list)` simplifica la tarea puesto que no hay que andar mirando si había aparecido antes o no ese `id` (si no había aparecido lo crea para el diccionario y le asocia una lista vacía).

Así pues:

```
from collections import defaultdict

result = defaultdict(list)
with open("datos.txt") as f:
  for linea in f:
    coord, id = linea.split(", 'id': ")
    result[id.strip()].append(coord.strip())
```

(los `.strip()` son para eliminar espacios supérfluos al inicio o fin de las cadenas y los retornos de carro)

Una vez terminado el bucle tendremos en el diccionario `result` una clave por cada  `id` diferente. Y asociada a cada clave una lista con las coordenadas encontradas para ese `id`. Así pues imprimirlo en el formato que necesitas es bastante trivial:

```
for id, coords in result.items():
  print("{},'id': {}".format(",".join(coords), id))
```

El resultado que sale es:

```
'coordenada': [{'origen':'4235433', 'destino':'5544225'}],'coordenada': [{'origen':'4235433', 'destino':'5544346'}],'coordenada': [{'origen':'4235433', 'destino':'5544890'}],'id': [{'nombre':'2345', 'nombre':'3432'}]
'coordenada': [{'origen':'7423333', 'destino':'5544225'}],'coordenada': [{'origen':'7423333', 'destino':'5544346'}],'id': [{'nombre':'9295', 'nombre':'4567'}]
```